# Extract all elements from a string separated by underscores using regex

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to capture all elements and store in separate column from the below string,seprated via underscores(campaign name for an advertisement) and then I wish to compare it with a master table having the true values to determine how accurate the data is being recorded.

eg: Input :  [image]

Expected output is :  [image]

My first element extraction was : `REGEXP_EXTRACT(campaign_name, r"[^_+]{3}")) as parsed_campaign_agency`

I only extracted first 3 letters because according to the naming convention(*truth table*), the agency name is made of only 3 letters.

**Caveat**: *Some elements can have variable lengths too. eg. The third element "CrossBMC" could be 3 letters in length or more.*

I am new to regex and the data lies in a SQL table(in BigQuery) so I thought it could be achieved via SQL's regex_extract but what I am having trouble is to extract all elements at once.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is input string have constant number of underscores?

Comment: Hi slava, yes the underscores are constant.

Comment: Please post you data as text, not picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If number of underscores constant and knows you can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) like:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(campaign_name,'_',1) first,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(campaign_name,'_',2),'_',-1) second,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(campaign_name,'_',3),'_',-1) third
FROM your_table;
```

Here you can try an example [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=398929ec0f7310cf5d55b8d9281616dd&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Quick question, If the data is available on biq query, I cannot use substring_index, is there an alternative function for the same

Comment: Use SPLIT function https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split for big-query